# Firebase : How many subscribers to a topic?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Is it possible to know how many Instance ID tokens have been subscribed to a topic with the Firebase API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no, you have to keep track of what topics an IID is subscribed to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Best idea is to consider implementing a simple counter/s in Firebase Realtime Database from your application whenever a user subscribes/unsubscribed from a topic you define. You can then query the variable/s however you wish.

Comment: is there a way to observe the subscription event?

Comment: Assuming it's web, Firebase offers listeners that fire every time data chages, I.e. on() call back. This link will guide you how to implement it with several simple examples - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: I get the idea, but that requires extra write to an database and triggering cloud functions, then again FCM could be easily used client-side only (as there is no persistence change, but only messages up-/downstream)

Comment: something like admin().messaging().onSubscription(...) would be nice - and then a counter like you proposed.

Comment: Depends on your use case, although writing to the database and having a registered listener in your application will suffice in many cases. However, I have implemented Cloud Functions to fire an FCM that listens to changes at a specified branch. Either way, you've got options available